Virtual-buttons option is not showing in Image target properties
I am trying to add Virtual Buttons on my Image target but I am not seeing "Add Virtual Button" button on Image target inspector tab.
There should be "Add virtual button" option on inspector tab.
Please help if anyone knows the solution

Sadly it seems that Virtual Buttons have been Depricated as of 10.22
if the funtionality is important to you attempt downgrading before that or to 9.8 and see if you can add Virtual buttons to your image targets

the API was removed in 10.22 https://developer.vuforia.com/library/release-notes/vuforia-engine-release-notes. 10.21 should still work, but clearly it is not recommended to to use a deprecated feature for anything else than a short lifespan project.
